# preg_match from JSON string in PHP

Tags: php, json, preg-match

i am need preg_match this 
  "supportsUnlock" : true,

code json

```
{
  "supportsUnlock" : true,
  "options" : [ "email", "questions" ],
  "account" : {
    "name" : "a@hotmail.com"
  },
  "emailAddress" : "a•••••@hotmail.com",
  "emailDomain" : "hotmail.com",
  "rescueEmail" : false,
  "forgotPasswordFlow" : true
}
```

Comment: why don't you just use `json_decode()` to get an easy modifyable object from that code?

Answer (score 1):

first store json in $json varibale

after decode it.

```
 $data = json_decode($json);

 print_r($data);
```

Check result after get it value by array.

Comment: this will return result in object not in array.

Comment: try `json_decode($json, true)` [(manual)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) function for getting values from json.

Example:

```
<?php
$json = '{
  "supportsUnlock" : true,
  "options" : [ "email", "questions" ],
  "account" : {
    "name" : "a@hotmail.com"
  },
  "emailAddress" : "a•••••@hotmail.com",
  "emailDomain" : "hotmail.com",
  "rescueEmail" : false,
  "forgotPasswordFlow" : true
}';

$decodeJson = json_decode($json,true);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($decodeJson);
echo $decodeJson['supportsUnlock']; // true

?>
```

**Result of print_r():**

```
Array
(
    [supportsUnlock] => 1
    [options] => Array
        (
            [0] => email
            [1] => questions
        )

    [account] => Array
        (
            [name] => a@hotmail.com
        )

    [emailAddress] => aâ€¢â€¢â€¢â€¢â€¢@hotmail.com
    [emailDomain] => hotmail.com
    [rescueEmail] => 
    [forgotPasswordFlow] => 1
)
```

Also note that, `json_decode(string,true)` will return result in array format if you need result in object than you can just remove the second param of `TRUE`.

Comment: file json in website http://testerjson.com/file/api/account

i need preg_match in values

Comment: @ThamerPhp: link is not working